# Deleting the set substring from string

Tags: java

I need to delete the set substring from string in Java. How I can to do it?
example:

`string st1="The end of the text";`
`string st2="end of the ";`

result:
`st1="The text".`

Comment: if this is homework please tag as such.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
String newString = st1.replace(st2, "");

// String newString2 = st1.replaceAll(st2, ""); Alternative
// String newString3 = st1.replaceFirst(st2, ""); Alternative 2
```

However, your question smell homework so you should add that tag on future questions if this is true.

[Java String documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 2):

Does the following do what you are looking for?

```
str1 = st1.replace(st2,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `substring()`, you can do it like this:

```
public static String getCustomString(String s1, String s2)
{
    if(s1.length() >= s2.length())
    {
        if(s1.contains(s2))
            return s1.substring(0, s1.indexOf(s2)) + s1.substring(s1.indexOf(s2) + s2.length());
    }
    else
    {
        if(s2.contains(s1))
            return s2.substring(0, s2.indexOf(s1)) + s2.substring(s2.indexOf(s1) + s1.length());
    }
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If homework (with minimal usage of Java API calls:

```
public void subString(String st1, String st2) {

   int s2len = st2.length();
   int s1len = st1.length();

   int i = 0;
   int count = 0;
   while(i <= st1.length() && i+st2.length() <= st1.length()) {

       if (st1.substring(i, i+st2.length()).equalsIgnoreCase(st2)) {
          st1 = (i > 0? st1.substring(0, i) : "") + st1.substring(i+st2.length());
          i=0;
       }
       else {
          i++;
       }
   }
   System.out.println(st1);
}
```

Otherwise:

```
st1.replace(st2, "");
```

Comment: This also covers the case where substring to be replaced has differences in case (upper/lower).