# How to delete a part of a string?

Tags: java

For example, if I have multiple strings of the type `something, $other` and I'd like to delete the part after the comma, so that I get `something` how can I do it? I remember that there was a way to do it using `%` or something but I can't find it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting the set substring from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811601/deleting-the-set-substring-from-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use string split to accomplish what you want

```
String s = "something, $other";
String whatYouWant = s.split(",")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the String api. You can get the index "something, $something".indexOf() of the comma. Then use that index and the substring() method.

Answer (score 0):

A version without using `.split()` and thus without iterating the entire string.

Using `substring`:

```
String s = "something, $other";
String whatYouWant = s.substring( 0, s.indexOf(","));
```